# My furnace has been going on and off erractically

Tags: hvac

Furnace goes on within 2-3 minutes of stopping.  It runs for about 4 minutes and goes off.  2 minutes it goes on.  Even after the temp. has reached 70. The outside temp is not that cold compared to what it could be.  It's in the upper 20s and lower 30s all day.  Thermostat is one year old.  Just had someone check furnace and said it was fine.  They had to install new humidistat.
Today, it ran for over 30 minutes even after reaching 70.  It went off and then started up immediately after stopping.  I called service man and they have not called me back.

Comment: 1 - Many thermostats will run a furnace 1 or 2 degrees *past* the set temperature - e.g., set for 70 and will run until 72, then stay off until down to 69. What temperature does it show when it finally stops? 2 - If thermostat has a battery (some do, some don't), change it, as a low battery can cause strange behavior.

Comment: It does not sound right that the furnace ran for 30 min after 70, what was the temperature reading then, 75 or even higher? I suspect the thermostat is in a location affected by drift, thus cooling faster than rest places in the house. Another possibility is the furnace has a lower rating than required to meet heating demand after activity such as an expansion.